# Prolog Queue of Tuples/Pairs using List without Duplicates

Tags: prolog, queue

I am attempting to implement a queue of tuples/pairs for use with an AI in SWI-Prolog. The goal is to first fill the structure with data and then evaluate each element. Each unique (X, Y) pair should be evaluated only once.

Currently, the problem is that my implementation is not a queue but a stack. The function dequeue is also evaluating to false prematurely. Here is a simplified portion of the code I am working with.

```
:- dynamic([queue/1, destination/2]).

enqueue(X, Y):-
     retract(queue(List)),
     \+member((X, Y), List),
     assert(queue([(X, Y)|List])).
enqueue(_,_).

dequeue:-
   retract(queue([(X, Y)|List])),
   retractall(destination(_, _)),
   assert(queue(List)),
   assert(destination(X, Y)).
```

.........................Actual Code Below.............................

```
add_to_list_of_dest(X, Y):-
    retract(list_of_dest(Stuff)),
    \+member((X, Y), Stuff),
    assert(list_of_dest([(X, Y)|Stuff])),
    format("List of Dest Added : (~d, ", X),
    format("~d)~n", Y).
add_to_list_of_dest(X, Y):-
    format("Duplicate Element Not Added : (~d, ", X),
    format("~d)~n", Y).

choose_destination:-
    current_pos(X, Y),
    destination(DestX, DestY),
    \+(X = DestX),
    \+(Y = DestY), 
    format("Choosing Desination : Currently Travelling~n").
choose_destination:-
    retract(list_of_dest([(X, Y)|Stuff])),
    retractall(destination(_, _)),
    assert(list_of_dest(Stuff)),
    assert(destination(X, Y)),
    format("Choosing Desination : (~d, ", X),
    format("~d)~n", Y).
```

Comment: You probably don't want to use assert and retract. It's really bad practice, trying to break the logical paradigm of prolog, and also can have poor performance. Why don't you represent your queue as a regular predicate argument?

Comment: There's not much to on here, but `dequeue` will fail if no fact of the form `queue([(X,Y)|List])` has been asserted yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ChristianF's answer is fine (+1), though appending to the end of a list will become burdensome for large queues. A well-known alternative uses two stacks. Doing so gives you O(1) insertion and amortized O(1) popping. The trick is having an input stack and an output stack. Assuming the output stack is in the right order, you just return the top item when it's non-empty to pop. If it is empty, take the input stack and reverse it onto the output stack.

```
% empty_queue(-Queue) is det.
empty_queue(queue([], [])).

% enqueue(+Item, +Queue, -NewQueue) is det.
enqueue(Item, queue(InStack, OutStack), queue([Item|InStack], OutStack)).

% dequeue(+Queue, -Item, -NewQueue) is det.
%    Handle the case where the output stack is ready to be used.
dequeue(queue(InStack, [Top|OutStack]), Top, queue(InStack, OutStack)).
%    Handle the case where the input and output stacks must be swapped.
dequeue(queue(InStack, []), Top, OutStack) :-
    reverse(InStack, NewOutStack),
    dequeue(queue([], NewOutStack), Top, OutStack).
```

You can take advantage of Prolog's non-determinism to make a single predicate with both calling conventions. This makes it work more similarly to `append/3`:

```
% queue(+Item, +QueueWithoutItem, -QueueWithItem) is det.
queue(Item, QueueWithoutItem, QueueWithItem) :-
    nonvar(Item), nonvar(QueueWithoutItem),
    enqueue(Item, QueueWithoutItem, QueueWithItem).

% queue(-Item, -QueueWithoutItem, +QueueWithItem) is semidet.
queue(Item, QueueWithoutItem, QueueWithItem) :-
    nonvar(QueueWithItem),
    dequeue(QueueWithItem, Item, QueueWithoutItem).
```

Answer (score 1):

Making a queue is really not hard if you know lists:

```
%% enqueue(+Queue, +Element, -NewQueue)
enqueue(L, E, L2) :- append(L, [E], L2).

%% dequeue(+Queue, -Element, -NewQueue)
dequeue([H|T], H, T).
```

Example use:

```
?- enqueue([], (2,3), L), enqueue(L, (4,5), L2), dequeue(L2, _Ignore, L3).
L = [ (2, 3)],
L2 = [ (2, 3), (4, 5)],
_Ignore = (2, 3),
L3 = [ (4, 5)].
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use difference_list, wich append in O(1) :

```
init_queue(U-U).

en_queue(Q, Elem, New_Q) :-     
    append_dl(Q, [Elem|U]-U, New_Q).

de_queue([H|T]-U, H, T-U).

check_queue(Elem, Q) :-
    Q = A-[],
    member(Elem, A).


append_dl(A-B, B-C, A-C).
```